How can I update the partition logic to exclude columns with all 0 values?
I am working on a table where I need to remove columns that have all zero values, and then update the partition logic based on the remaining columns. Currently, our partitioning logic does not account for the removal of columns with only zero values.
What’s the best way to implement this feature? Specifically, I want to:

Identify and hide columns where all values are zero.
Dynamically adjust the partition logic to consider only the remaining columns.


Welcome to StackOverflow, Please provide a minimal reproducible example like markdown tables containing your sample input data. Additionally please add more details or what things have you tried and attached your code snippets in your question.

I need to delete the whole column if column all values are 0

Yes that is already clear from your question text, but in this community you are supposed to post your efforts so far (see the minimal reproducable example link in the above comment). Post code that you have tried it with so we can help you debug.
